# Postponing gesture recognizer in swift (UISwipeGestureRecognizer)

Tags: swift, timer, swift4, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a swipe gesture recognizer that I turn off after the user swipes. That’s when I have a series of animations. 1st, a view will move in the direction that the user swipes. Then based on the location that it stops, another animation occurs based on the location that it stopped in. I then turn on the gesture recognizer all the way at the end of the function that handles this swipe. The problem is that the recognizer is turning on too quickly and therefore if the user were to quickly swipe in another direction, the animation would only occur in the wrong place (due to the fact that the view is in a different place). My question is, how can I create a function that waits X amount of time and then turns back on the recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1
var toDoSmth: (()->void)? = nil
// 2
toDoSmth = { 
     // turns back on the recognizer 
     // and do any delayed task
}

// 3
let delayedTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayedTime) {
     toDoSmth()
}
```

Here: 1, 2 - created variable/autoclosure; 
3 - run your code after 1 second.

Comment: That’s exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: How do I do that?